# how to reproduce 415 Unsupported Media type

Tags: google-drive-api

How to reproduce `415 Unsupported media type`?

I am trying with this with the upload to Google Drive.
Setup resumable upload so that I can add any media after the initial POST.
Thinking like during the first `POST`, the media type is not set completely. Google Drive will use some default option like `application/octet-stream`.

1. Then during the data file upload via `PUT`, will set the right media type.
   If the `PUT` is Not success, the response should be `415`
2. Second method could be by adding content-encoding during `POST`. If the encoding is not supported the response should be `415`.

Here is Python code I rewrote from Web. How to change this to get `415`?
Are there other methods to get this error? I am not familiar with `Javascript`, web resources are cryptic for me now.

```py
import json
import os
import requests


access_token ="ya29.XXX.....XXXqI"
filename = './test-atom.xml'

filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)

# 1. Retrieve session for resumable upload.

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}

params = {
    "name": "drive-small2.xml",
    #"mimeType": "application/atom+xml" ## works without this line
}

r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(params)
)

location = r.headers['Location']

# 2. Upload the file.


#headers = {"Content-Type": "application/atom+xml", "Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(filesize - 1) + "/" + str(filesize)} ## works for this also
headers = { "Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(filesize - 1) + "/" + str(filesize)} ## works for this also
r = requests.put(
    location,
    headers=headers,
    data=open(filename, 'rb')
)
print(r.text)

***********************

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\driveUpload>py resume-upload10.py
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1nQW6_-1F4fBEcKoln7vSM0qOTpWhSpZ2",
 "name": "drive-small2.xml",
 "mimeType": "text/xml"
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you trying to get an error?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to get the error message of 415.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to get an error? And have you tried putting anything on `Content-Type`?