# Exporting a Google Form

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm trying to use the Google Drive API to export a Google form (mime type 'application/vnd.google-apps.form') to some other format. The API I'm using is this (one example):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/export?mimeType=text/html
```

I found this documentation for the available export formats:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats

I've tried just about all of the mimeType outputs listed there, none work - I get http error 400.  Note that export does work fine with documents, presentations and spreadsheets. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was stated in [Google Workspace documents and corresponding export MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats), that an `About` resource contains an `exportFormats` field with a list of all supported export formats supported by the system for this user.

You can use [about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) method to get an [About resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about).

**Sample Response:**

```
"application/vnd.google-apps.form": [
   "application/zip"
  ],
```

- The only supported export format for Google Forms is a zip format based on my `About` resource

**Sample Export Request: (Google Forms to a zip file)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary I am finding ways to get an error response for any request. I am sending the request to Google Drive.
Can you provide the code snip or steps on how you get an error.

I have asked my question here.
[how to reproduce 415 Unsupported Media type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518211/how-to-reproduce-415-unsupported-media-type)

Tried resumable upload with initial w/o MIME type and with return URL, tried many MIME types. All the request go well.